# MySql select values of serialized column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have a column called **focus_areas_6**, in this column is stored as a serialized array.

Example: `a:2:{i:0;s:8:"bedrooms";i:1;s:7:"closets";}`

And I'm trying to get the rows where the field **focus_areas_6** match an array of values: `array( 'bedrooms' )`.

I saw some examples using `IN`, `ANY` OR `LIKE`, but that works if the variable is a single value and not an array.

Comment: Just do `focus_areas_6 LIKE '%s:8:"bedrooms"%'`

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, so serilize my php array and compare with the serialized field in the MySQL?

Comment: Storing serialized data into database is not a good practice!

Comment: @D.Dimitrov I don't have a choice, the value is stored that way by a plugin.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, Maria DB 15.1

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena ideally you should not store serialized data, but what I have given is just a simple hack to work in case of checking for 'bedrooms' key. You can very easily make it dynamic for another key values. For eg: if you want to check for 'tiger', count the number of characters in it, i.e., 5. So check for `LIKE '%s:5:"tiger"%'`

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102): may be what you are looking for?